# How can I create files in Azure Data Lake File Shares from .NET?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-lake-gen2

I've been trying to create a directory in an Azure Data Lake Gen2 file share. I can use the code below to create a blob container in the same storage account without error.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string storageUri = "https://xxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net";
            DefaultAzureCredential cred = new DefaultAzureCredential();
            DataLakeServiceClient serviceClient = new DataLakeServiceClient(new Uri(storageUri), cred);
            DataLakeFileSystemClient fileSystem = serviceClient.CreateFileSystem("test");
        }
```

How can I create a file share directory instead of a blob container? I've tried using `xxxxxxx.file.core.windows.net` instead of dfs, but get an error `AuthenticationErrorDetail: Authentication scheme Bearer is not supported for Files.`

This snip from Azure Storage Eplorer shows what I mean.

[storage explorer snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdQY5.png)

Is there a different API I need to use? Different auth ? Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Do you want to create a directory inside a blob container?

Comment: No, I want to create a directory inside an Data Lake file share. I am able to create a container (aka 'blob directory') using the code shown. I added a screen snip to better explain what I'm after.

Comment: Aah...I see. Basically you want to create a File Share inside an ADLS Gen2 Storage account. You will need to ShareServiceClient for that (use Azure.Storage.Files.Shares Nuget package) and your storage URI would be `https://xxx.file.core.windows.net`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @GauravMantri ! I loaded the API you recommended and am trying it now. ShareServiceClient cannot use DefaultAzureCredential, so I need to build different auth.

Comment: Awesome! You can use storage credentials (account name/key).

Answer (score 1):

This sample does what I need.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string storageUri = "https://xxxxxx.file.core.windows.net/myshare";
            string sas = "SAS credential to file share xxxxxx.file.core.windows.net/myshare. SAS must include create privilege.";

            AzureSasCredential cred = new AzureSasCredential(sas);
            ShareClient shareClient = new ShareClient(new Uri(storageUri), cred);
            Response<ShareDirectoryClient> resp = shareClient.CreateDirectory("test");
        }
```